# pipe two files as inputs of an script in linux command line

Tags: linux

I have 2 *.gz files. I want to cat them (zcat) and pipe them to a command as its inputs.

```
zcat file1.gz
zcat file2.gz
```

then pipe them in order as input

```
| script file1 file2  >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using bash or zsh, you can do this:

```
script <(zcat file1.gz) <(zcat file2.gz)
```

It's a bit more difficult otherwise, and I would probably use named pipes.

Comment: would please help me about named pipe for this case?

Comment: This should work.  It doesn't do any error checking at all, though.

    `mkfifo a; mkfifo b`
    `zcat file1.gz > a&`
    `zcat file2.gz > b&`
    `script a b`
    `rm a b`